# Horizontal lines in tabular with tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht

Let be the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*3{c|}}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{test} \\ \cline{2-3}
& test & test \\ \hline
test & test & test \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

A simple conversion with

```
make4ht tabletest.tex
```

produces a not very nice lines:

[image]

Horizontal ones are converted to double lines, crossings are not well connected, and broken lines are displayed for multicolumn cells.

Is it possible to configure/customize the appearance of the lines? I know this is just a cosmetic issue, but if there is any solution, I don't want to miss it out.

Comment: do you have up-to date TeX distribution? we changed style of horizontal lines in tables some time ago. the lines are connected when I compile your example.

Comment: Ok. I'll try TeX Live 2020 (I'm now using the 2018 version provided with Debian 10)

Comment: Ah, TL 2018 is definitely too old, multiple `make4ht` versions were released since then and dozens of [fixes](https://tug.org/tex4ht/changelog.html) were added to TeX4ht.